# Google App Engine: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on an application which allows users to upload an image file, which gets stored in the datastore. Here's how my model currently looks like:

```
class Sender(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
    food_type = db.StringProperty()
    pic = db.BlobProperty()
    file_name = db.StringProperty()
    base_city = db.StringProperty()
    source_address = db.StringProperty()
    dest_address = db.StringProperty()
```

Images uploaded by a user would be stored inside `pic`, who's datatype is assigned as a `Blob`.

I then provide a form for users to fill in their data and upload their image file:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Name:<input type = 'text' name = 'name'><br>
    Email ID: <input type = 'text' value = {{email_id}} name = 'email'><br>
    Quantity (in units):<input type = 'text' name = 'quantity'><br>
    Food type:<input type = 'text' name = 'food_type'><br>
    Food Pic<input type="file" name="file"/><br>
    Base City:<input type = 'text' name = 'base_city'><br>
    Source Address:<input type = 'text' name = 'source_address'><br>
    Destination Address:<input type = 'text' name = 'dest_address'><br>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

Here's the source code of the Handler that handles the data submitted from the above form:

```
def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
        quantity = int(self.request.get('quantity'))
        food_type = self.request.get('food_type')
        base_city = self.request.get('base_city')
        source_address = self.request.get('source_address')
        dest_address = self.request.get('dest_address')
        file_name = file_upload.filename

        sender = Sender(name = name, email = email, quantity = quantity, pic = file_upload.file.read(), file_name = file_name,
                            food_type = food_type, base_city = base_city, source_address = source_address, dest_address = dest_address)
        sender.put()
        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(sender.file_name)[0]
        self.render('senderpreview.html', sender = sender)
```

Source code of `senderpreview.html` wherein I'm trying to display the image uploaded by the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>PREVIEW:</h1>

    <br>
    Name: {{sender.name}} <br>
    Quantity: {{sender.quantity}}<br>
    Food Pic: {{sender.pic}}

  </body>
</html>
```

However, this is the error that I'm getting on submitting the form:

```
Food Pic: {{sender.pic}}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's wrong with my code? I went through a few questions posted on Stackoverflow under the same title but none seem to be of any help.

Comment: If looks like you are trying to insert the content of the blob (binary data?) into your template. That is not going to work.

Comment: What should be my approach if I want to display the image associated with that blob?

Comment: Write a view that returns the image from the blob, make sure you set the right headers (`Content-Type`). Then link the view in a `<img>` in the template.

Comment: How do I return the image from the blob in the first place? Sorry, I'm not really getting what I'm supposed to do here.